# Length of missing side in scalene triangle

Tags: geometry

I am trying to calculate the length of a side shared by two scalene triangles. Therefore both triangles share the two, fixed vertices defining the missing length. No angles are known but the lengths to the vertex opposite the shared side are.
[image]

In this diagram the unknown length is for side c. Lengths a and b are known at any time. Vertex ab travels on a straight line toward vertex bc.

If necessary a second, independent scalene triangle cxy is available sharing side c and with known lengths for sides x and y.

Knowing the lengths of two sides of these scalene triangles, can the length of the third side be calculated? Without angles I can not apply the Law of Sines but there seems to be enough information here to uniquely determine the length of side c.

Answer (score 0):

Denote adjacent angles near "vertex at time 2" as `F` and `Pi-F`

Using cosine theorem:

```
a1^2 = a2^2 + b1^2 - 2*a2*b1*Cos(F)
c^2 = a2^2 + b2^2 - 2*a2*b2*Cos(Pi-F) = a2^2 + b2^2 + 2*a2*b2*Cos(F)
```

Now express `Cos(F)` from the first equation and substitute int second one

```
Cos(F) = (a1^2 - a2^2 - b1^2)/ (2*a2*b1) 
c^2 = a2^2 + b2^2 + (a1^2 - a2^2 + b1^2) * b2 / b1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `b1` is the length of the side from 'Vertex at time t1' to the vertex where it says "Angle between sides b and c is constant". 
Denote by `alpha` the angle at 'Vertex at time t1'. Apply the law of cosines to the triangles:

1. triangle formed by side `a1`, `Vertex at time t1` and `Vertex at time t2`:

```
a2^2 = a1^2 + (b1 - b2)^2 - 2*a1*(b1 - b2)*cos(alpha)
```

2. triangle formed by side  side `a1`,  `Vertex at time t1` and side `c`:

```
c^2 = a1^2 + b1^2 - 2*a1*b1*cos(alpha)
```

From equation 1, express `cos(alpha)` and then plug it in equation 2:

```
c = sqrt( a1^2 + b1^2 - b1*( a1^2 + (b1 - b2)^2 - a2^2 )/(b1 - b2) )
```